# Changing class member address

Tags: c++, class, pointers, properties

Summarizing:

Is it possible to change a class member property memory address?

---

*What lead me to do this question:*

I'm not sure if what I want to do will lead into my expected behavior, and even if it works as expected, if it is what I should do.

So, I have a member property which I want to read from disk, say for instance that it is `prop` from `MyClass`. The routine I have that read the property from disk `getVarOnFile` I do not have access to the implementation, but it uses a pointer to the type to fill the value on the file.

In the documentation it says that if the property does not exists, the pointer may be null, although I am unsure if it will set it to null or it is because it expects that I enter null pointer to the function.

Because of that, instead of using the `destVar` pointer itself, I use a `localVar` pointer, and then set the `destVar` to `localVar`.

But I am not sure if I should do that, it seems that this will segment memory, where most of the members are close in the memory, but not this one that I set to the memory place reserved by the file.

```
void readHelper(const char* propOnFile, float*& destVar)
{
  // check if propOnFile exists
  float *localVar = nullptr; 
  getFileOnVar(propOnFile,localVar);
  if ( localVar != nullptr){
    destVar
  }
}

class MyClass {
  private:
    float prop;
  public:
    static MyClass *read(const char* file){
      readHelper("prop",&(this->prop));
    }
};
```

I am not sure what would happen to the original memory place reserved for the original class property member, which was replaced to a new place. It will be freed or this would be memory leak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Changing class member address

If I understand your question correctly, that is not possible.

Say you have:

```
struct Foo
{
   int a;
};

Foo f;
```

Once you have created `f`, the address of `f` and `f.a` are not changeable. You can only modify their values.